# Removing back of a linkedlist

Tags: c, linked-list

If there is one node left in a linked list and you attempt to remove it from the back in my program, it gives an error. I think I know why, but I can't solve it. See this is an assignment, and the rules are very strict, I am supposed to implement a header word by word, and for the removeFromBack function, we are supposed to remove the back node, then return a pointer to the removed node. But if there is only one node left, I cannot dereference a ptr->next to make it null, and that in turn is giving me problems. How would I solve this problem without changing any of my parameters? Here is my code

```
MusicRec * removeFromBack(MusicRec * theList)
{
    MusicRec *record;
    if(theList == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    else if(theList->next == NULL)
    {
        record = theList;
        theList = NULL;
        return record;
    }

    while(theList->next->next != NULL)
    {
        theList = theList->next;
    }

    record = theList->next;
    theList->next = NULL;

    return record;
}
```

Comment: Is the signature of `removeFromBack()` fixed or is it fixable? You're faced with a couple of options.  If the interface is fixed, you probably have to fail to remove the last node because it is also the first node.  If the interface is fixable, you could change the prototype to `Music *removeFromBack(MusicRec **pTheList)` and you use `*pTheList` in place of `theList` in your code. Your assignment `theList = NULL;` changes the local variable `theList`, but does not change the pointer in the calling function.

Comment: It is not prototypable like I said, my prof has an auto grader, and it has to be the exact way it was written in the header.

Comment: Is the quoted type of the function correct? You're returning a `Music *` (it says), but you're also returning `return record;` and `MusicRec *record;` only works if `Music` and `MusicRec` are two names for the same type. You also have a test `TheList == NULL`, which is testing a global variable that you've not shown us; can you set that to NULL?

Comment: I am sorry for all the typos, this is correct now. My code is giving so many errors and by the way the description for the function is as follows
/*removeFromBack(MusicRec *  theList)
Takes a pointer to the head of the list.  Removes the last
item from the head of the list.  Does not free the memory for 
the item removed.  Returns a pointer to the removed item.
Returns NULL if the list is empty.
*/

Comment: I'm guessing that `theList` is an anchor node. In other words, it's a statically allocated node that has no content, and is only used for its `next` pointer.  Therefore, you would never set `theList` to NULL, only its `next` pointer.

Comment: I know this, I explained it above. But I am trying to make it work somehow with what I am given.

Comment: Given the specification, the nearest you can do seems to be an 'infinitely removable end of list'.  Basically, when `theList->next == NULL`, you return `theList`.  If it is called again with the same pointer, you return it again.  Someone gets bored.  I don't see what else you can do without changing the rules.  It is slightly debatable whether this 'removes the last item from the head of the list', but with the interface specified, I think it is as good as you can do.

Comment: It cannot work with what you have been given. There must be something else, or removing one node from a one-node list is impossible, because there's nothing to remove it *from* (like the problem of executing the Cheshire Cat). But more importantly, **if the code is giving many errors, then you have written too much code.** You must correct errors as they appear, not pile more code on top of them.

Comment: To rephrase my previous comment, if `theList->next == NULL` then the list is empty, return NULL, do nothing else.

Comment: Well thanks for the help guys, if it can't be done, I will point it out to my prof